# Xampp Access Forbidden php

Tags: php, xampp

I'm a windows user. I've been using xampp for quite a while but suddenly none of my .php files are working now!
I get this error message:

---

Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 403

localhost
Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) OpenSSL/0.9.8y PHP/5.4.16

---

I can see the list of my .php files in localhost/Practice (Practice is the folder where I've saved my files)
The file even opens whenever I click on it.
But when I click on any 'submit' button inside any of my files, it gives this error.
Please help! I updated xampp from 1.8.1 to 1.8.2 but still the same problem persists!

Answer (score 172):

Try with this code below, add it in your virtual host config. Add this lines to `httpd-vhosts.conf` file:

```
<Directory "c:/<path-to-projects>/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I fixed the same issue by this way. Hope it helps.

**Note:**

after changes **please test it in incognito** because you redirected by cache

Comment: The key is `Require all granted`. That did the trick for me. Thanks!

Comment: I had the problem that my virtual hosts that linked to a folder that was not on C: wouldn't work and give me the mentioned error, but this answer finally fixed it!

Comment: after apply these changes please remove ssl plugins and or .htaccess files then test it again

Comment: it seems this doesnt work on my end

Answer (score 21):

The way I resolved this was setup error logs correctly, first

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/websites/test/"
    ServerName test.dev
    ErrorLog "D:/websites/test/logs/error.log"
    CustomLog "D:/websites/test/logs/access.log" common
    <Directory D:/websites/test/>  
        AllowOverride none
        Require all granted  
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

After this error are being logged into "D:/websites/test/logs/" *make sure to create logs folder yourself*. The exact error that was recorded in error log was

> AH01630: client denied by server configuration:

Which pointed me to correct solution using [this link](https://www.assistanz.com/resolved-ah01630-client-denied-server-configuration/) which said for the above error

```
Require all granted
```

is required. My sample sample code above fixes the problem by the way.

Comment: The question is about setup, API route may not be related to this

Answer (score 19):

For XAMPP on Mac

```
sudo chmod -R 0777 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/myprojectname
```

NOTE: remember to change 'myprojectname' to your actual project name. Also, make sure the project is on the root directory of htdocs or change the path accordingly.

Comment: Thanks This worked for me in my linux machine.

Answer (score 18):

if used ubuntu operating system then check chmod of /Practice folder
change read write permission

Open terminal press shortcut key
`Ctrl+Alt+T`
Goto

**$ cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/**

and change folder read write and execute permission by using `chmod` command

e.g folder name is practice and path of folder 
 /opt/lampp/htdocs/practice

Type command

```
$ sudo chmod 777 -R Practice
```

what is `chmod` and `777` ? visit this link
http://linuxcommand.org/lts0070.php

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: This is very insecure, you shouldn't give write access to anyone for the whole folder!

Comment: I think it should rather be sudo chmod -R 777  htdocs

Answer (score 7):

The only solution that worked for me after spending hours researching online

```
sudo chmod -R 0777 /opt/lampp/htdocs/projectname
```

Comment: Thanks this works by using the Xampp inbuilt terminal to execute the code

Answer (score 7):

Edit this file `C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf`
Change:

```
AllowOverride none
Require all denied
```

To

```
AllowOverride All
Options  All
Allow from all
Order allow,deny
```

Restart apache

Answer (score 5):

I am using xxamp using ubuntu 16.04 - and its working fine for me

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/"
    ServerAdmin localhost
    <Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 4):

Go in to your Xampp folder `xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-xampp.c­onf`

Edit the last paragraph:

```
#close XAMPP sites here 
.
.
.
Deny from all
.
.
```

to

```
#close XAMPP sites here 
.
.
.
Allow from all
.
.
```

or just watch this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZUAKLUZa-AU.

Comment: I've tried that! Did not work.. As I said, I can access localhost, but .php is not getting processed by any interpreter.

Comment: Look at the link you submit button is heading to , maybe its not a valid link. It has to submit the form to a file in the xampp directory where the others are. Also look for naming mistakes , maybe it is example.php but you wrote exampel.php ;)

Comment: Well I got it! Was some error in my code! Hadn't included some required files! That's why it was showing an error only when I clicked the submit button :) Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 3):

For me it was solved instantly by the following

1. Going to C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra
2. Editing inside the file httpd-xampp.conf
3. Edit the file as follows:

find the following lines by cont+f:

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin/"
<Directory "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
    Require local
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</Directory>
```

only change  local ----> all granted, so it becomes like this

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin/"
<Directory "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
    Require all granted
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</Directory>
```

After this the localhost will stop showing the error and will show admin panel. 
I found this solution in a video here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MvYyEPaNNhE

Answer (score 2):

Did you change any thing on the virtual-host before it stop working ?

Add this line to xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost localhost:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
    ServerAdmin localhost
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem after moving the htdocs folder to outside the xampp folder. If you do this then you need to change the document root in httpd.conf. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1414/3543329.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. So I got remembere. Yesterday I had commented this code in htttp-xampp.conf

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin/"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
#        AllowOverride AuthConfig
#        Require local
#        ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
    </Directory>
```

SO I can access my localhost using other system on same network(LAN/WIFI) as it make localhost require local.

So I just make it like

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin/"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
#        Require local
        ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
    </Directory>
```

and now its working on my local machine and also localhost is accessible using other systems on same LAN/WIFI.

Answer (score 1):

### WAY-1

- *this is for a specific project/ folder inside `htdocs` folder*

1. open your **cmd/ terminal** and go to the `htdocs` folder directory for me it was ( /opt/lampp/htdocs/ ) and I used the ( **cd directory_name** ) command for changing the directory

   `cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/`
2. then run the below command

   `sudo chmod 777 -R Project-Folder-Name`

replace the **Project-Folder-Name** with your **project folder name**

### WAY-2

- *this is for all projects/ folders inside `lampp` folder*

1. open your **cmd/ terminal** and go to the `lampp` folder directory for me it was ( /opt/lampp/ ) and I used the ( **cd directory_name** ) command for changing the directory

   `cd /opt/lampp/`
2. then run the below command

   `sudo chmod 777 -R htdocs`

Answer (score 1):

I might be late but the error was resolved after I created a new folder inside htdocs and pasted all the files from the folder I was getting an error.

In my impression the problem is not in XAMPP but in the folder read/write permissions.

Answer (score 0):

```
A. #LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
B. <Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

**Replace with:**

```
A. LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
B:
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

From *E:*\xamp**apache\conf/httpd.conf**

Comment: This opens your whole disk up to any hacker that successfully gains access to your web server. Thats so very nice of you to make their lives nice and easy!

Comment: If you dont understand what a section of the `httpd.conf` file does, its better to look it up in that manual before giving such bad advice to others

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error because somehow deleted the index.php and accessing the folder without
index.php gave same error.

Answer (score 0):

following steps might help any one

1. check error log of apache2
2. check folder permission is it accessible
   ? if not set it
3. add following in vhost file
   <Directory "c://">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride all
   Order Deny,Allow
   Allow from all
   Require all granted
4. last but might save time like mine check folder name(case sensitive "Pubic" is different form "public") you put in vhosts file and actual name.
   thanks

Answer (score -1):

In my case I exported Drupal instance from server to localhost on XAMPP. It obviously did not do justice to the file and directory ownership and Apache was throwing the above error.

This is the ownership of files and directories initially:

[image]

To give read permissions to my files and execute permission to my directories I could do so that all users can read, write and execute:

```
sudo chmod 777 -R
```

but that would not be the ideal solution coz this would be migrated back to server and might end up with a security loophole.

A script is given in this blog: https://www.drupal.org/node/244924

```
#!/bin/bash

# Help menu
print_help() {
cat <<-HELP
This script is used to fix permissions of a Drupal installation
you need to provide the following arguments:

  1) Path to your Drupal installation.
  2) Username of the user that you want to give files/directories ownership.
  3) HTTPD group name (defaults to www-data for Apache).

Usage: (sudo) bash ${0##*/} --drupal_path=PATH --drupal_user=USER --httpd_group=GROUP
Example: (sudo) bash ${0##*/} --drupal_path=/usr/local/apache2/htdocs --drupal_user=john --httpd_group=www-data
HELP
exit 0
}

if [ $(id -u) != 0 ]; then
  printf "**************************************\n"
  printf "* Error: You must run this with sudo or root*\n"
  printf "**************************************\n"
  print_help
  exit 1
fi

drupal_path=${1%/}
drupal_user=${2}
httpd_group="${3:-www-data}"

# Parse Command Line Arguments
while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; do
  case "$1" in
    --drupal_path=*)
        drupal_path="${1#*=}"
        ;;
    --drupal_user=*)
        drupal_user="${1#*=}"
        ;;
    --httpd_group=*)
        httpd_group="${1#*=}"
        ;;
    --help) print_help;;
    *)
      printf "***********************************************************\n"
      printf "* Error: Invalid argument, run --help for valid arguments. *\n"
      printf "***********************************************************\n"
      exit 1
  esac
  shift
done

if [ -z "${drupal_path}" ] || [ ! -d "${drupal_path}/sites" ] || [ ! -f "${drupal_path}/core/modules/system/system.module" ] && [ ! -f "${drupal_path}/modules/system/system.module" ]; then
  printf "*********************************************\n"
  printf "* Error: Please provide a valid Drupal path. *\n"
  printf "*********************************************\n"
  print_help
  exit 1
fi

if [ -z "${drupal_user}" ] || [[ $(id -un "${drupal_user}" 2> /dev/null) != "${drupal_user}" ]]; then
  printf "*************************************\n"
  printf "* Error: Please provide a valid user. *\n"
  printf "*************************************\n"
  print_help
  exit 1
fi

cd $drupal_path
printf "Changing ownership of all contents of "${drupal_path}":\n user => "${drupal_user}" \t group => "${httpd_group}"\n"
chown -R ${drupal_user}:${httpd_group} .

printf "Changing permissions of all directories inside "${drupal_path}" to "rwxr-x---"...\n"
find . -type d -exec chmod u=rwx,g=rx,o= '{}' \;

printf "Changing permissions of all files inside "${drupal_path}" to "rw-r-----"...\n"
find . -type f -exec chmod u=rw,g=r,o= '{}' \;

printf "Changing permissions of "files" directories in "${drupal_path}/sites" to "rwxrwx---"...\n"
cd sites
find . -type d -name files -exec chmod ug=rwx,o= '{}' \;

printf "Changing permissions of all files inside all "files" directories in "${drupal_path}/sites" to "rw-rw----"...\n"
printf "Changing permissions of all directories inside all "files" directories in "${drupal_path}/sites" to "rwxrwx---"...\n"
for x in ./*/files; do
  find ${x} -type d -exec chmod ug=rwx,o= '{}' \;
  find ${x} -type f -exec chmod ug=rw,o= '{}' \;
done
echo "Done setting proper permissions on files and directories"
```

And need to invoke the command:

```
sudo bash /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/fix-permissions.sh --drupal_path=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/rkmission --drupal_user=daemon --httpd_group=admin
```

In my case the user on which Apache is running is 'daemon'. You can identify the user by just running this php script in a php file through localhost:

```
<?php echo exec('whoami');?>
```

Below is the right user with right file permissions for Drupal:

[image]

You might have to change it back once it is transported back to server!