# xampp - Access forbidden error new

Tags: php, xampp

I've heard this happen on different occassions so I checked older xampp version fixes, but nowadays xampp file/folder structures have changed and I couldn't find solution.
If I go localhost/ - Everything works.
If I go example.dev/ - Access forbidden!

Where and what should I exactly change?
I installed xampp 7.0.13 version.

Comment: can you please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17816732/xampp-access-forbidden-php hope you got the sollution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understand correctly

All you have to do is to edit the httpd-xampp.conf

from **Require local** to **Require all granted** in the LocationMatch tag.

That's it!