# XAMPP Access Forbidden

Tags: php, xampp, windows-10, php-7.2

I have just downloaded the latest version of XAMPP with PHP version 7.2.4. I have made a very simple PHP validation for a HTML form and when I press submit it comes up with the following:

> Access forbidden!
> You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 403
> localhost
> Apache/2.4.33 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0g PHP/7.2.4

I'd don't know what the problem is as I have tried changing `Require none` to `Require all granted`.

Please Help!

Comment: try this it is very helpful for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/23594870/14913109

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have experienced this problem and found out that localhost link is not configured in 
httpd_vhosts.conf. 
So I added this line at the bottom part of httpd_vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "E:/xampp/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: after applied these changes please test it in incognito

Answer (score 1):

Well, probably this must be happening because the localhost link is not configured in your xamp vhost, try to look for the vhosts configuration file and add the same one there. Just add this block of code making the appropriate path changes until your repository so that you can access the localhost:

```html
# Virtual Hosts
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@hcode.com.br
    DocumentRoot "C:\ecommerce"
    ServerName www.hcodecommerce.com.br
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
<Directory "C:\ecommerce">
        Require all granted

        RewriteEngine On

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I copied this code into the acpache\conf\httpd.conf file and have changed the file directories and not Apache isn't even running and it shows this error [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3336:tid 584] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.`

Comment: Require all granted
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]

This worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By default in httpd.conf your entire system directory "/" is secured and not allowed access

in httpd.conf:

```
# Deny access to the entirety of your server's filesystem. You must
# explicitly permit access to web content directories in other 
# <Directory> blocks below.
#
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

Add the below additional  under the above

```
<Directory /home>
   Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
   AllowOverride All
   Require local
</Directory>
```

Change /home to your hosted installation public directory - e.g. /projects  or /devsite.local etc...

For more info on Apache  see here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory

The 'Options' are typical .htaccess directives - change as needed

The 'AllowOverride All' gives access to the /home folder and everything under it

The 'Require local' makes sure only localhost / 127.0.0.1 has access to folder and files under /home

Hope this helps :D