# it always show the error 403 aka Access Forbidden. It says that "You dont have permission to access the requested object..."

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp, localhost

I'm making a 'Sign In' page for my Website using Codeigniter but when I click the 'Sign In' button, it always shows the error *403 Access Forbidden*. It says that

> "You don't have permission to access the requested object...".

How to overcome this error?

Comment: Hi, could you give more information on how your application is built? Share some of your code of the home page and sign-in page, etc...

Comment: are you using virtual host or directly calling through your localhost. ?

Comment: Which OS you are using ? Linux ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give premission.
If you run this from linux here simple way

> sudo chmod 755 -R /opt/lampp/htdocs/

or

> sudo chmod 755 -R /var/www/html

OR you can try this one
[Xampp Access Forbidden php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17816732/xampp-access-forbidden-php)