# Can't access php my admin due to "Access forbidden!"

Tags: php, xampp

I have recently had to reinstall XAMPP on my Macbook and as a result of this I can no longer access PHP My admin. When I navigate to the phpmyadmin directory I receive this error:

> Access forbidden!
>
> New XAMPP security concept:
>
> Access to the requested object is only available from the local
>   network.
>
> This setting can be configured in the file "httpd-xampp.conf".
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 403

Obviously this is really, really annoying, so any help would be awesome, thanks in advance!!!

PS: I am trying to connect from the same machine that XAMPP is installed and running on

Comment: see it : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17816732/xampp-access-forbidden-php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xampp Access Forbidden php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17816732/xampp-access-forbidden-php)