# How to allow users to access the file they created on my server? (XAMPP)

Tags: php, xampp

I've encountered a **403 Forbidden error** where it won't allow the currently logged in user to get their profile picture. I understand WHY the error is there but I'm unsure on how to fix it.

I get that the error means that the user cannot access the file because they lack the permission to do so, however I don't know how to give that user the permission to get it (So I can display the image). The only solution I know is `chmod` but that seems to be for existing files whereas I'm trying to do it for new files. I don't have a .htaccess file either in my XAMPP folder which I'm using to create the server.

I've altered the httpd.conf file in Apache - C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin/ from `Require local` to `Require all granted` but that also doesn't seem to remove the error.

I don't think showing my code will be useful here, it functions correctly since the only error I receive is the 403.

Comment: The user that needs permission to read the file is not the person that's logged in, it's the system account that's running the web server. Whatever process is responsible for creating/uploading the image file needs to set those permissions.

Comment: [this post has resolved same problem so you can take a look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17816732/xampp-access-forbidden-php)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xampp Access Forbidden php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17816732/xampp-access-forbidden-php)