# codeigniter 3 giving error 403 on xampp server (arch linux)

Tags: linux, server, xampp, codeigniter-3, http-status-code-403

This is my first time using codeigniter and so far i have created a few sites using xampp but after i extracted the codeigniter files in htdocs/ it doesn't show up here is what happens: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMEhG.jpg

I am a native linux user so i tried using chmod command, specifically:
`sudo chmod -rwx codeigniter/`
`sudo chmod -R 0777 codeigniter/`
`sudo chmod o-rwx codeigniter/`

i also tried the method mentioned here: [Xampp Access Forbidden php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17816732/xampp-access-forbidden-php)

it still doesn't work, what am i missing here? Let me know if you need more details
also i am using archlinux as my os

Comment: You should go to `http://localhost/dashboard/codeigniter/` to display your CodeIgniter website.
Also make sure the `$config['base_url']` in `application/config/config.php` is set to that same url.

Comment: @Marleen I did that but it gives me this ( https://imgur.com/a/Z7ZElI1 ) page and whenever i try either of the links, it just shows me the same error page, the xampp is installed in my root folder, can that be a problem?

Comment: That is the page you should be seeing when you've successfully set up CodeIgniter. The paths you're seeing to are not links, they refer to files you need to edit to start creating your website with CodeIgniter. The link to `User Guide` may not work either, even though you've successfully set up CodeIgniter: the download for CodeIgniter used to come with documentation, but they've removed that at some point and probably forgot to update the link on the Welcome page.

Comment: You can find the documentation for CodeIgniter 3 here: https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/ then follow along with the `Tutorial` (link in the menu on the left), this should help you get started building your website with CodeIgniter.